# JButton in separate class file

Tags: java, swing, class, jbutton

I wrote class which contain simple JFrame and I want to add button from other
class to this JFrame

When I'm trying to write

```
panel.add(new CancelButton())
```

I got an error: LoginWindow.java:29: error: no suitable method found for add(CancelButton)

Can you help me with it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class LoginWindow {

public LoginWindow(){

//Login Window
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Movie date base");
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//label
JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcom to Movie Date Base! ");
label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18));
//panel
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//add panel to the frame
frame.add(panel);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//Grid layout
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.insets = new Insets(100,10,10,10);
panel.add(label,c);

   }
}

import javax.swing.*;

public class CancelButton {
public CancelButton(){

JButton cancel = new JButton("cancel");

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to treat your CancelButton class as a JButton, then it has to extend JButton.

```
public class CancelButton extends JButton{
   public CancelButton(){
      //call the parent-level constructor
      super("cancel");

  }
}
```

Note that I've gotten rid of your cancel variable here, since your CancelButton class **is-a** JButton now. You can use it anywhere you can use a JButton.

However, if instead you want to use the cancel variable in other classes, then you need to create some kind of getter function for it:

```
public class CancelButton {

   JButton cancel;

   public CancelButton(){
      cancel = new JButton("cancel");
   }

   public JButton getButton(){
      return cancel;
   }
}
```

Then you would call that getButton() function, like this:

```
panel.add(new CancelButton().getButton())
```

Which approach you take really depends on exactly what you're trying to do, and how you want to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep it like it is, put the button into an array, and in the jframe, instantiate the cancel class and call from the array.